# Number of solutions with higher probability

Tags: python, algorithm

Given a grammar list and string list

grammar list is a list sort by probability of occurrence that  looks like (p is probability)

```
123W456 (p=0.9)
1%W3W456 (p=0.8)
...
```

where `W` is string (alphabetical words),

`W` is selected from the string list (sort by p), which looks like

```
Hello (P=0.9)
Hi (P=0.8)
...
```

Therefore the word `123Hello456` has probability `(p=0.9*0.9)`
and the word `1%Hi3Hello456` has the probability `(p=0.8*0.8*0.9)`

My problem is given a string say `1%Hi3Hi456`, I want to get the number of words that has a higher probability than `1%Hi3Hi456` `(p=0.8*0.8*0.8)`.

What I am thinking now is the to do by brute force, generate of words in descending probabilities (e.g., `123Hello456`,...) until `1%Hi3Hi456`.
Is there a more efficient method?

Comment: The `python` tag is irrelevant here

Comment: Is `1%Hi3Hello456` valid?

Comment: How can a word be "Hello" with probability 0.9 and "Hi" with probability 0.8?

Comment: @user3386109 yes it is valid

Comment: @Anonymous assume the probability is given

Answer (score 1):

It's given that the probability of `1%Hi3Hi456` is `0.8*0.8*0.8 = 0.512`, and we're looking for strings that have higher probability.

---

Starting at the beginning of the grammar list, we see that `123W456` has a probability of `0.9`. Using that information, we can compute the minimum probability of `W` as

```
p = 0.512 / 0.9 = 0.56888
```

Which is to say that any word in the word list that has a probability greater than `0.56888` will work with the grammar `123W456`. If the word list is sorted by probability, then a binary search can be used to determine the number of acceptable words in *O(logN)* time.

---

The next grammar, `1%W3W456`, is a little more problematic. Dividing the grammar probability, we have

```
p = 0.512 / 0.8 = 0.64
```

but that leaves the problem that `p1 * p2 > 0.64` where `p1` and `p2` are the probabilities of two words in the word list. One way to solve is to choose the first word with a linear search for words with `p1 > 0.64`, and then do the binary search for words with

```
p2 > 0.64 / p1
```

Comment: Thanks, overall, the number of W could be up to 7 and 8, but this method seems to be quite optimal

Comment: Given W as length 7, this algorithm requires O(n^7*(log(n))

Comment: @william007 Yes, it's best for small W (1,2, maybe 3). With larger W you're relying on the fact that the linear searches get shorter as the target probability gets higher, but the big-O complexity doesn't reflect that.